# Scripts won't run on QPython3

Tags: python, python-3.x, qpython, qpython3

I'm trying to run scripts on qpython3, android 5.0.1 and when executing the scripts nothing happens. Even the example scripts that are installed with the app. Interactive mode/running commands in console does work, only scripts don't. What could be the reason?

Comment: That's the same for me. Only pip work on my android device. 4.4.2

Answer (score 1):

I had that issue on 4.4.4. Hit Run in the editor, then in the console it brings up you can cd to the directory the program is in and use the command 'python file.py' to start the program. It's a little annoying, but it's better than not being able to run programs at all. This problem disappeared for me on 5.1.1.